# De-Dupe lines in CTE based off of one key in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am not really sure on what I need with my issue. In the CTEs below I get an out put that gives me all the columns I want, but I am getting duplicates lines because a member can have two different type of Diagnosis code, What I want is to have one line per Member ID and then along with the DX codes so for example ...

```
MEMBERID    FIRST_NAME     BIRTHDATE    DIAGNOSIS_CODE
999999999   John            9/9/9999        E11.9
999999999   John            9/9/9999        E79.8
```

I Want the output to be like this

```
MEMBERID    FIRST_NAME     BIRTHDATE    DIAGNOSIS_CODE DIAGNOSIS_CODE
    999999999   John            9/9/9999        E11.9        E79.8
```

See now its one line per member, this is my code below and it runs without any issues, I am just trying to get one line per member please. The example above are just for the example not actually in my code but thought it be easier to read the example, rather then my code. any help is greatly appreciated

```
WITH

Dates as ( Select  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate,'MM'),-12) as MONTH1_BEGINDATE,
       LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1)) MONTH12_LASTDATE

         from dual   ---- requestor wants a rolling 12 month period         
), --select * from Dates

DX AS (Select  dx.diag_cd as Diagnosis_code, --- pulling in all members who have Diabetes DX regardless of date span from tab6 in ICUE for AZ
dx.mbr_id

From icue.mbr_diag dx

where dx.diag_cd in ('E08.00','E08.01','E08.10','E08.11','E08.21','E08.22','E08.29','E08.311','E08.319','E08.321',
'E08.329','E08.331','E08.339','E08.341','E08.349','E08.351','E08.352','E08.353','E08.354','E08.355',
'E08.359','E08.36','E08.37','E08.39','E08.40','E08.41','E08.42','E08.43','E08.44','E08.49',
'E08.51','E08.52','E08.59','E08.610','E08.618','E08.620','E08.621','E08.622','E08.628','E08.630',
'E08.638','E08.641','E08.649','E08.65','E08.69','E08.8','E08.9','E10.10','E10.11','E10.21',
'E10.22','E10.29','E10.311','E10.319','E10.321','E10.329','E10.331','E10.339','E10.341','E10.349',
'E10.351','E10.352','E10.353','E10.354','E10.355','E10.359','E10.36','E10.37','E10.39','E10.40',
'E10.41','E10.42','E10.43','E10.44','E10.49','E10.51','E10.52','E10.59','E10.610','E10.618',
'E10.620','E10.621','E10.622','E10.628','E10.630','E10.638','E10.641','E10.649','E10.65','E10.69',
'E10.8','E10.9','E11.00','E11.01','E11.10','E11.11','E11.21','E11.22','E11.29','E11.311',
'E11.319','E11.321','E11.329','E11.331','E11.339','E11.341','E11.349','E11.351','E11.352','E11.353',
'E11.354','E11.355','E11.359','E11.36','E11.37','E11.39','E11.40','E11.41','E11.42','E11.43',
'E11.44','E11.49','E11.51','E11.52','E11.59','E11.610','E11.618','E11.620','E11.621','E11.622',
'E11.628','E11.630','E11.638','E11.641','E11.649','E11.65','E11.69','E11.8', 'E11.9','E13.00',
'E13.01','E13.10','E13.11','E13.21','E13.22','E13.29','E13.311','E13.319','E13.321','E13.329',
'E13.331','E13.339','E13.341','E13.349','E13.351','E13.352','E13.353','E13.354','E13.355','E13.359',
'E13.36','E13.37','E13.39','E13.40','E13.41','E13.42','E13.43','E13.44','E13.49','E13.51',
'E13.52','E13.59','E13.610','E13.618','E13.620','E13.621','E13.622','E13.628','E13.630','E13.638',
'E13.641','E13.649','E13.65','E13.69','E13.8','E13.9') ---- all dx Diabetes code, pulling per request 

),  --select * From DX

members AS (

Select distinct -- need to dedup  by member ID
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 2 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MemberID,
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 1 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as SubscriberID,
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 3 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MemberAlternateID,   
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 6 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MedicaidRecipientNumber,
mb.fst_nm as first_name,
mb.lst_nm as last_name,
trunc(mb.bth_dt) as birthdate,
dx.Diagnosis_code

from DX dx

inner join dates dd
on 1=1 

inner join icue.mbr mb
on dx.mbr_id = mb.mbr_id


inner join icue.mbr_cov c -- pull in dates
on mb.mbr_id = c.mbr_id

inner join icue.mbr_id d -- member identifier 
on dx.mbr_id = d.mbr_id
and d.mbr_id_typ_id in ('2','3','1','6')


and c.pol_iss_st_cd ='AZ' ---- Policy state lmiting to AZ only 
and (c.lob_typ_id='12' OR c.clm_pltfm_id='A9')  ---Community and state

),  --select * from members

Members_with_diabetesDX AS (
Select m.*,dd.MONTH1_BEGINDATE, dd.MONTH12_LASTDATE from members m
inner join dates dd on 1=1
) select * from Members_with_diabetesDX
```

Comment: These columns names are not allowed: DIAGNOSIS_CODE DIAGNOSIS_CODE. They are duplicates; You can combine them as an array set. Is it acceptable to you?

Comment: Perhaps `PIVOT` and `ROW_NUMBER` will be useful.

Comment: Ah, pivot sounds like it will work didn't think about that. I will give it a try, thank you .

Comment: How many duplicates can you have in a group? If it is at most two, that is fine (or even if it is at most **n** for some number **n** known in advance), but otherwise you will either lose some information or you must use dynamic SQL - not the easiest thing for inexperienced developers.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I realized I had this similar issue and went with a long way but its the only way I know ( for now) . I did the row_number and then I criteria off of the alias I did with the row number and I got the output I was looking for . I will post my code. I know some might find it messy and long but its what I know and I am confident in my results.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for your help. I went ahead and used row_number then I criteria off of the Alias I did with ro_number . Below is my code.

```
 WITH

Dates as ( Select  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate,'MM'),-12) as MONTH1_BEGINDATE,
       LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1)) MONTH12_LASTDATE

         from dual   ---- requestor wants a rolling 12 month period 

), --select * from Dates

DX AS (Select  dx.diag_cd as Diagnosis_code, --- pulling in all members who have Diabetes DX regardless of date span from tab6 in ICUE for AZ
dx.mbr_id

From icue.mbr_diag dx

where dx.diag_cd in ('E08.00','E08.01','E08.10','E08.11','E08.21','E08.22','E08.29','E08.311','E08.319','E08.321',
'E08.329','E08.331','E08.339','E08.341','E08.349','E08.351','E08.352','E08.353','E08.354','E08.355',
'E08.359','E08.36','E08.37','E08.39','E08.40','E08.41','E08.42','E08.43','E08.44','E08.49',
'E08.51','E08.52','E08.59','E08.610','E08.618','E08.620','E08.621','E08.622','E08.628','E08.630',
'E08.638','E08.641','E08.649','E08.65','E08.69','E08.8','E08.9','E10.10','E10.11','E10.21',
'E10.22','E10.29','E10.311','E10.319','E10.321','E10.329','E10.331','E10.339','E10.341','E10.349',
'E10.351','E10.352','E10.353','E10.354','E10.355','E10.359','E10.36','E10.37','E10.39','E10.40',
'E10.41','E10.42','E10.43','E10.44','E10.49','E10.51','E10.52','E10.59','E10.610','E10.618',
'E10.620','E10.621','E10.622','E10.628','E10.630','E10.638','E10.641','E10.649','E10.65','E10.69',
'E10.8','E10.9','E11.00','E11.01','E11.10','E11.11','E11.21','E11.22','E11.29','E11.311',
'E11.319','E11.321','E11.329','E11.331','E11.339','E11.341','E11.349','E11.351','E11.352','E11.353',
'E11.354','E11.355','E11.359','E11.36','E11.37','E11.39','E11.40','E11.41','E11.42','E11.43',
'E11.44','E11.49','E11.51','E11.52','E11.59','E11.610','E11.618','E11.620','E11.621','E11.622',
'E11.628','E11.630','E11.638','E11.641','E11.649','E11.65','E11.69','E11.8', 'E11.9','E13.00',
'E13.01','E13.10','E13.11','E13.21','E13.22','E13.29','E13.311','E13.319','E13.321','E13.329',
'E13.331','E13.339','E13.341','E13.349','E13.351','E13.352','E13.353','E13.354','E13.355','E13.359',
'E13.36','E13.37','E13.39','E13.40','E13.41','E13.42','E13.43','E13.44','E13.49','E13.51',
'E13.52','E13.59','E13.610','E13.618','E13.620','E13.621','E13.622','E13.628','E13.630','E13.638',
'E13.641','E13.649','E13.65','E13.69','E13.8','E13.9') ---- all dx Diabetes code, pulling per request 

),  --select * From DX

members AS (

Select distinct -- need to dedup  by member ID
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 2 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MemberID,
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 1 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as SubscriberID,
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 3 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MemberAlternateID,   
max(case when d.mbr_id_typ_id = 6 then d.mbr_id_txt end) over (partition by d.mbr_id) as MedicaidRecipientNumber,
mb.fst_nm as first_name,
mb.lst_nm as last_name,
trunc(mb.bth_dt) as birthdate,
dx.Diagnosis_code

from DX dx

inner join dates d
on 1=1 

inner join icue.mbr mb
on dx.mbr_id = mb.mbr_id
--and mb.orig_sys_mbr_id in ('2','3')

inner join icue.mbr_cov c -- pull in dates
on mb.mbr_id = c.mbr_id

inner join icue.mbr_id d -- member identifier 
on dx.mbr_id = d.mbr_id
and d.mbr_id_typ_id in ('2','3','1','6')

and c.pol_iss_st_cd ='AZ' ---- Policy state lmiting to AZ only 
and (c.lob_typ_id='12' OR c.clm_pltfm_id='A9')  ---Community and state

),  --select * from members

Members_with_diabetesDX AS (
Select 
m.MemberID,
m.SubscriberID,
m.MemberAlternateID,   
m.MedicaidRecipientNumber,
m.first_name,
m.last_name,
m.birthdate,
m.Diagnosis_code,
row_number() over (partition by m.MemberID order by m.Diagnosis_code Desc) as Rank,
d.MONTH1_BEGINDATE, 
d.MONTH12_LASTDATE 

from members m
inner join dates d on 1=1
),-- select * from Members_with_diabetesDX 

Final as ( 
Select 
ff.MemberID,
ff.SubscriberID,
ff.MemberAlternateID,   
ff.MedicaidRecipientNumber,
ff.first_name,
ff.last_name,
ff.birthdate,
max(case when ff.Rank = 1 then ff.Diagnosis_code end) over (partition by ff.MemberID) as firstdx,
max(case when ff.Rank = 2 then ff.Diagnosis_code end) over (partition by ff.MemberID) as secdx,
max(case when ff.Rank = 3 then ff.Diagnosis_code end) over (partition by ff.MemberID) as thirddx,
max(case when ff.Rank = 4 then ff.Diagnosis_code end) over (partition by ff.MemberID) as fourthdx,
ff.MONTH1_BEGINDATE, 
ff.MONTH12_LASTDATE,
row_number() over (partition by ff.MemberID order by ff.Diagnosis_code,ff.SubscriberID,ff.MemberAlternateID,ff.MedicaidRecipientNumber,ff.first_name,ff.last_name,ff.birthdate Desc) as uniquerow

from Members_with_diabetesDX ff



) select * from Final where uniquerow ='1'
```